# Joining multiple attachments into a pdf

Tags: attachment, pdf, merge

I have multiple attachments of type image,pdf,text,word etc. I want to merge them into a single pdf. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Currently I'm facing the similar issue and it seems like there are two ways to go:

1. Use some AppExchange application. I've tried WebMerge, but there are few more worth a try for sure, just search for 'pdf merge'. They seem to work surprisingly well, one can use loops in patterns, there is usually user interface and Apex API. The biggest disadvantage here is that in most (all?) cases the documents are processed outside our org, often making it useless.
2. Second approach is to create your own remote service (in .NET, Java or something) that would wait for the request from Apex, fetch PDFs via some Salesforce API and send it back merged.

Answer (score 1):

I assume its possible to do in Apex, but would certainly not be easy, and would likely be very ugly.

I know that Conga Composer works well for any sort of PDF creation.

> **I don't work for, or have any affiliation with Conga, just have used
>   it in the past for creating PDFs from multiple sources and it worked fairly well.  Take
>   that for what it's worth**

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000016b7FEAQ

Comment: I want this through apex.

Comment: You think it is possible in Apex? I've never been able to do it.

Comment: I assumes you could do this by deserializing attachments and adding them to a blob. Using that blob to construct a PDF.  I could be wrong, never tried to do it, just assumed it was possible.  Like I said I assumed it would not be pretty or easy, but maybe I am wrong.